# Delete specific characters from only two columns in a CSV file using Python 3.5

Tags: python, mysql, regex, csv

I am trying to edit a CSV file containing 4 million rows of data with 19 columns. There are two columns (the third and fourth) which list names of individuals, and the way their names are listed are "LastName, FirstName."

```
C00431445,"P80003338","Obama, Barack","DUCLOS, DUNCAN","CHICAGO","IL","606601303","OBAMA FOR AMERICA","ACCOUNTING MANAGER",77.65,08-AUG-08,"","","","SA17A","753821","5433431","P2008",
```

This is problematic because when I try to upload this file into MySQL using a delimiter of commas, it splits these 2 columns' names in half. I want to use Python 3.5 to select these two columns and remove the commas from inside them only, without deleting the commas in the other rows.

I am somewhat of a novice when it comes to coding and any help is appreciated. I know it's possible to split these columns using .split() and then merging them sans commas, however I wanted a cleaner method which would remove the commas directly from this file.

Comment: This looks valid CSV, what tool are you using for loading data into MySQL?

Comment: Not entirely sure what you mean by "what tool," I'm using SQL queries to create, alter my table to add in an auto-increment primary key and then querying it all only to find that my data splits along the names because the first and last name are separated by commas. I'd attach my queries but there isn't enough space in the comments section, apparently.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use csv module to read and write

```
import csv

f = open('file.csv', 'rb')
reader = csv.reader(f)
your_list = list(reader)


f = open('file.csv', 'wb')
writer = csv.writer(f, delimiter=',', quotechar='"', quoting=csv.QUOTE_ALL)

for line in your_list:
   line[2] = line[2].replace(",","")
   line[3] = line[3].replace(",","")
   writer.writerow(line)
```

Comment: Thanks, I realized after more research that the CSV module is probably the best way for me to figure this one out.

Answer (score 0):

In MySQL, read the columns into @variables, then manipulate them as you store them into the actual columns:

```
LOAD DATA ...
    (id1, id2, @name1, @name2, ...),
    SET name1 = REPLACE(@name1, ',', ''),
        name2 = REPLACE(@name2, ',', '');
```